# Something wrong with my gdb or KDevelop IDE?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, kdevelop

I have Ubuntu 9.04 and KDevelop IDE.
When I am trying to debug C++ console app, it tells me:
GDB cannot use the tty* or pty* devices.
Check the settings on /dev/tty* and /dev/pty*
As root you may need to "chmod ug+rw" tty* and pty* devices and/or add the user to the tty group using "usermod -G tty username".
I installed gcc and gdb, and project compiles OK. Do you have any suggestions? 
(My apologizes if it is a noobie question)

Comment: Have you tried doing what it said you have to do?
- Check the settings on /dev/tty* and /dev/pty* As root you may need to "chmod ug+rw" tty* and pty* devices and/or add the user to the tty group using "usermod -G tty username".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried what is being suggested? It seems that you have a permission or a group configuration issue on the character device gdb is trying to use to write things back to you.

Here's what to do:

- If you know the root password of your system, issue the following commands at a terminal/shell prompt:

  `su -`

  *you will be asked to enter the root password*

  `chmod ug+rw /dev/tty*`

  `exit`
- If you know what a sudoer is and if you are one, issue the following command:

  `sudo chmod ug+rw /dev/tty*`

Then try debug your program again.